# Launching Sublime Text 2 on the command line doesn't result in opening the specified file

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, sublime-text-2

When I type

```
subl ~/.profile
```

I expect Sublime to open my .profile file. This works with some files, although I couldn't find a pattern to which files.

Is this a bug in Sublime or have I done something wrong?

Comment: It happens to me as well. I have the feeling it only fails when Sublime isn't open yet.

Comment: Using `subl -n <file>` helps?

Comment: If `subl -n` helps when it is closed, I suppose you could create a shell script named `subl` that first checks if the process is running, and if not, adds `-n`. A better solution would be Sublime Text 2 adds this feature within its code of course :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Sublime Text 2 version 2.0.2 build 2221. Are you using an outdated `subl` you copied somewhere? What happens when you use the one in `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/`?

Comment: If `subl -n` helps, add this to your `.bashrc` - `alias subl='if [[ $(ps -ef | grep sublime_text | grep -v grep) ]]; then subl; else subl -n; fi'`